# r as.numeric change big values even with as.character

Tags: r

I'm struggling to convert some big numbers to numeric in R while using "as.numeric"; even when combining it with as.character.

I have a character class column whose values are all numeric. To be specfic, 23 numbers in each value.

While trying to covert the whole column to numeric, the values are changing, and even if I try to do it just with one value I have the same problem (in numeric or character format)

that's what I've being trying:

```
as.numeric(as.character(20161128000215091389073))
as.numeric(as.character("20161128000215091389073"))
as.numeric(20161128000215091389073)
or
as.numeric(as.character("20161226000750155832528"))
as.numeric(as.character(20161226000750155832528))
as.numeric(20161226000750155832528)
```

returns respectively:

```
20161128000215089938222
and
20161226000750157496020
```

I couldn't make it return the same number... any ideas?

Comment: Try using `gmp` library , `gmp::as.bigz("20161128000215091389073")`

Comment: Thank you Ronak,

bigz worked properly... I just got another problem... if the number has leading zeros... the return is NA... is there any Argument that would ignore the leading zeros?

Comment: You can try removing all the leading zeroes using `sub`, `gmp::as.bigz(sub("^0+", "","0000000000020161128000215091389073"))`

Comment: cheers mate! problem solved! =)